# Are burn marks on a flash unit window normal?

Tags: flash, equipment-damage

My flash unit has been accumulating small burn marks on its window.  Is this normal wear and tear or equipment damage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meltdown of flash front lens will happen when too much heat has accumulated. The temperature of flash will rise with

- hot ambient temperature
- shooting several shots at or near full power in quick succession
- shooting with high-speed sync near capabilities of flash
- light modifiers that keep the flash from cooling

The more those conditions are true, the more likely will you burn the front lens. Some flashes have temperature control circuits to keep you from using the flash when it's too hot already. However, sometimes running a hot flash cannot be avoided to get the photos you want; so yes, I'd consider it normal wear and tear.